Is it possible to under-watt from power source (battery) to better control Linux draining?
I would like to know if can i set a battery profile from its own. Maybe something like:
battery-model.default_profile= 

{powersave[underwatt-minimal],

normal[scalling-power-permitted-from-powersave],

performance[high-***watt/h***-limited-by-power-suply]}

I know about undervolt/overclock CPU.
We should make Linux scaling from availability AC/battery like macOS even Android both do (incredible 20h battery support).
maybe intel_pstate.default_source should include bt/pwr source parameters or acpi-cpufreq.default_source (kind of traffic-shapping, machine/kernel/modules/userspace)

This cannot be done, in general, with most existing computers. A few allow changes in BIOS, such as max CPU speed, but that varies by PC make and model. Had you mentioned specifics, there might, or might not, be a meaningful answer.

@DrMoishePippik system76 main page says UP to 14 hours some notebooks/laptops, with dgpu

What is "system 76"? What is "14 hours?"

@DrMoishePippik system76 is a Linux notebook vendor ( open hardware) like Tuxedo i think. Their promise is UP to 14 hours battery lifespan. www.system76.com

The laptop hardware cannot be under-volted. The electronics inside run at a specific voltages provided by the power supply or battery.
You cannot increase or decrease that voltage, without causing the laptop to have issues. This could be random glitches, data loss, damage to the hardware; including completely destroying the laptop.
As for Linux, all major distributions allow you to set the power to a "Power Saving" profile.
That being, Linux just isn't great on laptops right now for battery life. Maybe that will change in the future.

I understand your point, but if we cant undervolt officially, why not make reverse engineering ( ec firmware ). Not a easy task. That firmware controls keyboard/fans and even battery ...

@LuizCarlos The firmware is cryptographically signed and protected against modifications on many modern systems for security purposes. Undervolting has also been disabled on many systems to prevent side-channel attacks on processors via exploits such as plundervolt  where data can be leaked on a slightly undervolted system. You cannot just "edit the firmware", it is a complex system that only the system or motherboard designers can easily edit or change.
